# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x,\sin nt)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x,\sin y)d y$ for continuous $f$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x,\sin nt)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x,\sin y)d y$$ for continuous $f$?

It sounds like Riemann's lemma. But I am unable to do it.

Comment: $x$ seems to be just a dummy variable.

Comment: Well, are you interested in finding such $f$. If not elaborate the problem. It's unclear.

Comment: And also $x$ looks like a constant, as it's independent of $t,y$.

Comment: Approximate $f$ by a polynomial and use periodoicity if $\sin t$.